IDE1007 Имя не существует в текущем контексте

столкнулся с такой проблемой при попытке вызвать шрифт
код
    PrivateFontCollection collection = new PrivateFontCollection();
    collection.AddFontFile(@"C:\Projects\MyProj\free3of9.ttf");
    FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Free 3 of 9", collection);
    Font font = new Font(fontFamily, height);


Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

А теперь открываем сааамые основы языка и смотрим, где должен находиться исполняемый код. Увидите там небось что-то про методы, не так-ли? Тело класса служит для объявления членов (полей, методов, свойств и т.д.), а не для выполнения инструкций.
